# Excel: Format number with minimum decimal points but leave bigger decimal points

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I want a number format where I can specify minimum decimal points. So if a value has less that minimum decimal points then Excel will put the necessary decimal points. But if the value has more decimal points than the minimum decimal points then Excel would not do anything.

For example suppose the minimum decimal points is 2.
So if the value is 23 then Excel will show 23.00.
If the value is 23.1 then Excel will show 23.10.
If the value is 23.6923 then Excel will show 23.6923.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `0` for the ones that must show and `#` for the optional

```
0.00#########
```

[image]